# Android activity open facebook

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity

I am using the following code to open facebook page of the application. The code works fine but the facebook page opens blank until i swipe it down to refresh then it shows the content

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    System.out.println("ccccccccccccc");
                    String facebookUrl = "https://facebook.com/appsaraai";
                    try {
                        int versionCode = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;

                        if (versionCode >= 3002850)
                        {
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + facebookUrl);
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // open the Facebook app using the old method (fb://profile/id or fb://page/id)
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/395215577269747")));
                        }
                    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                        // Facebook is not installed. Open the browser
                        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(facebookUrl)));
                    }

                }
            });
```

any idea!

Answer (score 0):

Remember have a similar issue.

Try the mobile url :

instead of

```
String facebookUrl = "https://facebook.com/appsaraai";
```

use

```
String facebookUrl = "https://m.facebook.com/appsaraai";
```